Orthogonal diagonalization of symmetric tensor
Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n \times n$ real symmetric tensor ($A_{ijk} = A_{ikj} = A_{jik} = A_{jki} = A_{kij} = A_{kji} \ \forall i,j,k$ in a basis).  According to this paper, we can always write $A=\sum_{l=1}^r\lambda_l v_l\otimes v_l\otimes v_l$ for some scalars $\lambda_l$ and unit vectors $v_l$. Given a basis of orthonormal unit vectors $e_i$, the matrix elements of $A$ are given by $$A_{ijk}=A(e_i,e_j,e_k)=\sum_{l=1}^r \lambda_l (v_l)_i(v_l)_j(v_l)_k,$$
where $(v_l)_i$ is the $i$'th component of the vector $v_l$.
My question is: Is the matrix $V$ defined by $V_{li} = (v_l)_i$ orthogonal? And what about the generalized case for an $n\times n \times \cdots \times n$ tensor?

No, $V$ is not in general orthogonal.
It is possible that $r > n$ and the matrix $V$ is not even square.
The simplest example for this is $A = e_1 \otimes e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_1 \otimes e_2 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_1 \otimes e_1$, which requires three summands in a decomposition. For example, we can take $$A = \sqrt2 \left(\frac{e_1 + e_2}{\sqrt2}\right)^{\otimes 3} + \sqrt2 \left(\frac{-e_1 + e_2}{\sqrt2}\right)^{\otimes 3} - e_2^{\otimes 3}.$$
Even if $r = n$, then the matrix $V$ is not necessarily orthogonal. If it is orthogonal, then the tensor is called an odeco (orthogonally decomposable) tensor. See for example this paper.
